# Select the interactive window used with shift+enter in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I am currently using VSCode with Jupyter notebooks. I use the feature where shift+enter sends the line of code to an Interactive Window which works great. When I close and reopen my project, more often than not when I press shift+enter, VSCode creates a new Jupyter notebook interactive window instead of using my previously saved one which already has all my code. Is there a way to select the interactive window that I want so that I don't have to re execute all my code from scratch every time to fill in my notebook?

I tried looking around on the web for these settings but have not been able to find anything relevent.

Comment: I wonder if any relation to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/10808. but that's supposed to be fixed? if you raise a new issue ticket, please ping me with a link.

Comment: @starball I read that, and I'm not fully sure I understand what its supposed to do... I don't know if what I am asking is a feature that is available or it might just not be possible